# attribute in class can't be saved why

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class, oop

I'm trying to  coding in c#, I have two main classes first one is router and this is it's implementation

```
public class Router
{
    public int RouterValue = 0;
}
```

this I use this class in another class called Route which contains list of routers and this is implementation :

```
public class Route
    {
        public List <Router> routers = new();
        bool exitLoop = false;
        public void ReadInput()
        {
            Router router = new();
            Console.WriteLine(" \n Please enter data Input : \n ");
            for (int i = 0; !exitLoop ; i++)
            {
                router.RouterValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("router value" , router.RouterValue);
                routers.Add(router);
                
                if (routers[i].RouterValue == 0)
                {
                    exitLoop = true;
                }
            }
        }
        public void OutPut()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("out put : \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < routers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(routers[i].RouterValue);
            }
        }
        public int count()
        {
            return routers.Count;
        }
        public int sum(List<Router> _routers)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < routers.Count; i++)
                sum += _routers[i].RouterValue;
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

but when i create a Roue object and trying to enter values it's print them as ZERO'S and the sum also equals zero, So where is the problem ? i debug it and trying to put setters ang getters but all of it can't help, any one have an idea about it ?

this is the part in my main class where i added values :

```
Routes.Add(op.CreatRoute());
                Routes[^1].ReadInput();
                Routes[^1].OutPut();
```

Comment: You're not actually setting a value anywhere for it.

Comment: This is a common error: _Router router = new();_ is outside the loop. So you are adding the same object to the list and, at each loop, you change the same RouterValue until you press 0 and exit the loop. The result for every element inserted is the same. They are all referencing the same object with RouterValue equal to zero

Comment: @Steve ops thats true !! but How can it be dispensed with?

Comment: Just moving the line inside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only ever creating one `Router` object:

```
Router router = new();
```

Everything you do just updates that one object.  And the *last value* you enter (to terminate the loop) is `0`, so the last value that one `Router` object ever has is `0`.

(This is a good opportunity to step through the code in a debugger and observe the runtime values of your variables.  You'll find that the `routers` field on your `Route` object always has exactly *one* element in it, no matter how many times you iterate that loop.)

Create the new `Router` object inside the loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; !exitLoop ; i++)
{
    Router router = new(); // <--- here
    router.RouterValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("router value" , router.RouterValue);
    routers.Add(router);
            
    if (routers[i].RouterValue == 0)
    {
        exitLoop = true;
    }
}
```

That way each iteration of the loop creates (and appends to the list) an entirely new instance of a `Router`, rather than always operating on the same instance.

As an aside, this is also a good practice of keeping variables defined *only in the scope where you need them*.  This makes the code overall simpler and easier to follow, and helps you encapsulate functionality as the complexity of an application grows.